# How to sum array and other data?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

How can I use simple SQL to get same result?

I have two table like this.

```
create table t1_before
(
  k1 String,
  ts DateTime,
  span  Int32,
  iserror  Int32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (k1, ts)
;
```

```
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',1,0);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',1,0);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',1,1);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',2,0);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',2,0);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',2,1);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',2,1);
insert into t1_before values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00',2,1);
```

```
create table t1
(
  k1 String,  
  ts DateTime, 
  totalspan  Int32,  
  maxspan  Int32, 
  totalcount  Int32,   
  errorcount Int32, 
  goal Nested    
    (
        m UInt32,  
        n UInt32
)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (k1, ts)
;
```

table t1 is aggregation by t1_before.  goal.m is span, goal.n is count.
data in t1_before exchange to t1. 
like this:

```
insert into t1 values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00', 13, 2, 7, 2, [1,2],[3,5]);
```

t1_before have too many line, so actually I only have table t1.

if data is

```
insert into t1 values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:00', 13, 2, 7, 2, [1,2],[3,5]);
insert into t1 values('key1','2019-05-04 10:00:20', 25, 4, 8, 3, [1,2,4],[1,2,5]);
insert into t1 values('key1','2019-05-04 11:02:30', 13, 2, 8, 1, [1,2],[3,5]);
insert into t1 values('key2','2019-05-04 10:00:00', 13, 2, 8, 3, [1,2],[3,5]);
insert into t1 values('key2','2019-05-04 10:02:00', 13, 2, 8, 0, [1,2],[3,5]);
```

I know How to get result,but complex.

```
SELECT 
    d1.k1, d1.ts2, d1.a1, 
    d2.sumtotalspan, d2.maxtotalspan, d2.sumtotalcount, d2.sumerrorcount
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        k1, ts2, quantilesExactWeighted(0.5, 0.9, 0.99)(m1, n1) AS a1
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            k1, 
            toStartOfHour(ts) AS ts2, 
            goal.m AS m1, 
            sum(goal.n) AS n1
        FROM t1 
        ARRAY JOIN goal
        GROUP BY  k1, toStartOfHour(ts), goal.m
    ) 
    GROUP BY k1, ts2
) AS d1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        k1, 
        toStartOfHour(ts) AS ts2, 
        sum(totalspan) AS sumtotalspan, 
        max(totalspan) AS maxtotalspan, 
        sum(totalcount) AS sumtotalcount, 
        sum(errorcount) AS sumerrorcount
    FROM t1 
    GROUP BY k1, toStartOfHour(ts)
) AS d2 ON (d1.k1 = d2.k1) AND (d1.ts2 = d2.ts2)
```

┌─k1┬─ts2─┬─a1──┬─sumtotalspan─┬─maxtotalspan─┬─sumtotalcount─┬sumerrorcount
│ key1 │ 2019-05-04 10:00:00 │ [2,4,4] │      38 │    25 │     15 │     5 │

│ key2 │ 2019-05-04 10:00:00 │ [2,2,2] │      26 │    13 │     16 │     3 │

│ key1 │ 2019-05-04 11:00:00 │ [2,2,2] │      13 │    13 │      8 │     1 │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────

3 rows in set.

is any simple SQL(remove join) get same result?
like this,but is error:

```
SELECT 
            k1, 
            toStartOfHour(ts) AS ts2, 
sum(totalspan) AS sumtotalspan, 
        max(totalspan) AS maxtotalspan, 
        sum(totalcount) AS sumtotalcount, 
        sum(errorcount) AS sumerrorcount,
            quantilesExactWeighted(0.5, 0.9, 0.99)(sumMap(goal.m, goal.n))
        FROM t1 
        GROUP BY  k1, toStartOfHour(ts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this with goal.m/goal.n and [arrayReduce](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#arrayreduce-agg-func-arr1):

```sql
SELECT arrayReduce('sumMap', [[1, 2, 3, 3]], [[4, 5, 6, 7]])
FORMAT TSV

([1,2,3],[4,5,13])
```

Answer (score 0):

clickhouse is greate, function can combination.
In "Aggregate function combinators https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/combinators/", I see "-Array".So I find this function seem to be get same result:
quantilesExactWeightedArray(0.5,0.9,0.99)(goal.m , goal.n)